# After changing hostname, gedit (and other X clients) don't open

Tags: ubuntu, authentication, ubuntu-12.04, x11, xorg

After changing the hostname `gedit` is not working as expected, it shows error always in my root "No protocol specified"

```
** (gedit:23330): WARNING **: Could not open X display
No protocol specified
Cannot open display: 
Run 'gedit --help' to
```

Comment: How do you change the hostname? By hand (i.e. editing /etc/hostname) or by using a tool?

Comment: i change host name using this command sudo hostname master.192.168.1.44

Comment: Ok. You can check if your new hostname have an entry in `/etc/hosts` else add it. But, I am not sure this is the real issue ...

Comment: ya i added like this 192.168.1.44     master.192.168.1.44 in hosts using gedit

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's not only `gedit` that is going to fail but actually all programs that use the X11 protocol to talk to the graphics server. X11 uses the Xauth protocol to authenticate connecting clients. When you login through some kind of a display manager, a `MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1` authentication cookie is created and written into your `~/.Xauthority` file. That file is read by X11 clients and the cookies available there are used to authenticate the connections.

The list of cookies in your `~/.Xauthority` file can be displayed using `xauth list`:

```
$ xauth list
localhost:1012  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  bd988401cbf8xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
some.host.example.com/unix:1012  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  bd988401cbf8xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

If you change your host name, the X11 client library will no longer be able to find a matching cookie in the authentication database and the X11 server will reject the unauthenticated connection (unless configured otherwise).

What you can do is to add a matching cookie using `xauth`:

```
$ xauth add "$(hostname)/unix:0" MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 bd988401cbf8xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

`$(hostname)` expands to the result of the `hostname` command and `unix:0` corresponds to your `DISPLAY` environment variable being set to `:0.0`. If it is to another display number, e.g. `:ddd.0`, then you should change the added host entry accordingly to `"($hostname)/unix:ddd"`. Note also that the value of the cookie being added should match the value of the existing one.

If you don't have a terminal emulator open at that time and you are unable to open one because of the authentication error, you could switch to the console (text mode), login there and execute the above command.

Comment: To clean up the coockie of the previous hostname:

    xauth remove old-hostname/unix:0

Answer (score 0):

Simply restart the machine to take effect the hostname change.

Comment: That is not sufficient to fix the problem - editing the .Xauthority file does the trick, as specified in the accepted answer

Comment: Bit of a drastic solution for a Linux machine - restarting is only "simple" if you don't use the machine for real work!

Answer (score 0):

[jnweiger commented Aug 13, 2014](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/issues/514#issuecomment-52016939):

> The Xauthority file can be written in a way so that the hostname does
>   not matter.
>
> I am not sure, if `xauth` has a proper command line to specify the
>   Authentication Family, but I use `sed` to switch to Authentication
>   Family **'FamilyWild'**. We need to change the first 16 bits of the
>   `nlist` output. The value of **FamilyWild** is `65535` or `0xffff`.
>
> ```
> xauth nlist :0 | sed -e 's/^..../ffff/' | xauth nmerge -
> ```

In this case, the string written after the family number (usually, a hostname etc.) does not matter for matching at all.

In ALT's [xauth](https://packages.altlinux.org/en/Sisyphus/srpms/xauth) package, there has been applied a [patch](http://git.altlinux.org/people/george/packages/?p=xauth.git;a=commitdiff;h=bc78aa61cfbddaa27dee275f639ba40de6981b17) recently to support adding such **FamilyWild** entries via `xauth` directly with an `*:0` argument:

```
From bc78aa61cfbddaa27dee275f639ba40de6981b17 Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
From: George V. Kouryachy (Fr. Br. George) <george@>
Date: Fri, 4 Aug 2017 18:37:33 +0300
Subject: [PATCH] parse_displayname: use FamilyWild for *:0

---
 xauth/gethost.c  |    4 ++++
 xauth/parsedpy.c |    4 ++++
 2 files changed, 8 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)

diff --git a/xauth/gethost.c b/xauth/gethost.c
index 8cb58c5..598ac48 100644
--- a/xauth/gethost.c
+++ b/xauth/gethost.c
@@ -180,6 +180,10 @@ struct addrlist *get_address_info (
      * information to be copied and set len to the number of bytes.
      */
     switch (family) {
+      case FamilyWild:         /* was :0 */
+   src = "\xff\xff";
+   len = strlen(src);
+   break;
       case FamilyLocal:            /* hostname/unix:0 */
                    /* handle unix:0 and :0 specially */
    if (prefix == 0 && (strncmp (fulldpyname, "unix:", 5) == 0 ||
diff --git a/xauth/parsedpy.c b/xauth/parsedpy.c
index 97988d3..6c98339 100644
--- a/xauth/parsedpy.c
+++ b/xauth/parsedpy.c
@@ -141,6 +141,10 @@ parse_displayname (const char *displayname,
        family = FamilyInternet;
    }
 #endif
+    } else if (len == 1 && *displayname == '*') {
+   /* ALT: wildcard cookie */
+   host = copystring("*", 1);
+   family = FamilyWild;
     } else if (!dnet && (*displayname == '[') && (*(ptr - 1) == ']')) {
    /* Allow RFC2732-like [<IPv6NumericAddress>]:display syntax */
    family = FamilyInternet6;
-- 
1.7.3.3
```

Answer (score -1):

When I changed the name of my laptop I experienced this problem as well.
However I managed to fix it with the following commands

`su`

(enter password)

`cd /etc`

`gedit hosts`

From there I simply removed the reference to the old computer name and replaced it with the new.

`127.x.x.x  localhost
 127.x.x.x  (New Name)`

However Note that whenever you make changes to your computer name, you must ensure that the changes are made in both the `/etc/hostname` file as well as the `/etc/host` file. If you make 1 change without making the other, you will get an error.